# Request method not recognized after promisification

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, request, jasmine, aws-api-gateway

I built an API using AWS API Gateway and Lambda, now I am writing end to end tests, I am using Promise from bluebird and request, so I promisified request like this:

> Promise.promisifyAll(require('request'));
>   Promise.promisifyAll(request);

Now when I make requests (POST, PUT, GET), using request.methodAsync, the method is not recognized by the API Gateway !

I launched Jasmine with :

> NODE_DEBUG=request  jasmine

I can see the method = 'POST' or whatever, but the API still not recognize the method of the requests I am making with the promisified request ! any one run into this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm from the Api Gateway team. As long as the request is sent to a valid resource path / HTTP method pair on a deployed API, Api Gateway will accept it. Please note you'll need to put the stage name as the first path part in the URI (see example in the Api Gateway console on the Stages page).

If you're invoking the right API resource, the issue sounds like a client-side bug.

Jack

Comment: Thanks for your help, it turns out there is a bug when you Promisify the request module, so I used another nodejs module. now every thing works perfectly, but I still can't understand how the event my Lambda function called with have no method, especially it is coming from the mapping template, that the API Gateway build it based on the request it got ?!